# Getting "Uncaught TypeError" on one function, while the other one which is the same works properly

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have an issue with this function, returning an error: "Uncaught TypeError: storedId.indexOf is not a function. " and I have no idea how to get rid of it. The biggest issue is, that I have this very same function (this ones for movies, the other one is for tv shows), and the one for tv shows works as expected, while this one does not. To make it even worse, I had the same code on my github repo, where I was test-hosting the website, and it works perfectly there, and its literally the same code. Even tried copy-pasting the whole code for the whole script file, and it still returns the same error. The error started showing yesterday, when I went on to "tidy" my code as my project is 99% done, and just wanted to polish it out so I can then start hosting it. I have no idea why it does this, so any sort of help would help a lot, even guidance to what docs to read... Thanks in advance.

Here's the function that gives me the error:

```
//Add movie to watch list. Bug - > Uncaught TypeError: storedId.indexOf is not a function.
function addToList(id){
    let storedId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies")) || [];
    if(storedId.indexOf(id) === -1){
        storedId.push(id);
        localStorage.setItem("movies", JSON.stringify(storedId));
        //Notification that it will be added to Watchlist.
        const added = document.getElementById("added");
        added.innerHTML = "Added to watchlist !"
        added.classList.add("added");
        setTimeout(() => {
            added.classList.remove("added");
        }, 1500);
    } else {
        //Notification that it has already been added to the watchlist.
        const alreadyStored = document.getElementById("alreadyStored");
        alreadyStored.innerHTML = "Already in watchlist !"
        alreadyStored.classList.add("alreadyStored");
        setTimeout(() => {
            alreadyStored.classList.remove("alreadyStored");
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

If needed, here's the whole script file on hastebin:
https://hastebin.com/licomupere.coffeescript

Comment: It means that the result of parsing the JSON is a value that's not of a type that has an `.indexOf()` method on the prototype; so, something that's not an array or a string (like, say, an object).

Comment: Well that's really weird, because it worked yesterday with literally the same code lol .. damn this is getting painful :|

Comment: Yes, the one "addToList" is for something like a "watchlist", while the other function "favorite" is for favorite movies list.

Comment: Even when I do a "console.log(storedId) " or just "console.log(id)" within that function - addToList - it logs the movie ID (a few numbers), so it works exactly the same as the favorites one, but returns an error...

Comment: The way I understand it, the `JSON.parse` works and returns an object that doesn't have a `indexOf` function in its prototype chain. I'm guessing what's serialized in your `movies` local storage is not an array, but an object. Can you check that?

Comment: The issue now gets on a whole new level lol, i just opened mozzila to see if it works there, and it works perfectly .... while in chrome is the same

Comment: Copy paste data stored in Firefox to the same key in your local storage in chrome?

Comment: I seem to have fixed my issue. It seems that I got the localStorage stuck or it bugged out. So someone suggested me to do Array.from(storedId) and to define that as a variable, so I did, and that unstuck or whatever the local storage. I then (un)intentionally did the same thing for my series watch list, and this time when the same error occured, I just cleared session and local storage from within F12 -> application.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed my issue. It seems that I got the localStorage stuck or it bugged out. So someone suggested me to do Array.from(storedId) and to define that as a variable, so I did, and that unstuck or whatever the local storage. I then (un)intentionally did the same thing for my series watch list, and this time when the same error occured, I just cleared session and local storage from within F12 -> application. It's all working good now, so if anyone happens to get in a similar situation, try this option.